# transform a 3D numpy array into a list of 3 indices

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So I have large 3D data matrix, say *10000X10000X1000*, now what I need to do is to go over every element of the 3D data matrix and write to a file the indices and the values of 2 different matrix with the same size, an example of a line:

```
i j k val1 val2
```

What I currently do is run in 3 nested loops and prints it the following way, example of 2 small 3D data matrix and the approach:

```
import numpy as np


vv1= np.array([[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],
                [[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8]],
                [[7,8,9],[8,9,10],[9,10,11]]])

vv2= np.array([[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],
                [[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8]],
                [[7,8,9],[8,9,10],[9,10,11]]])

for x in range(vv1.shape[0]):
    for y in range(vv1.shape[1]):
        for z in range(vv1.shape[2]):
            print("{:} {:} {:} {:} {:}".format(x,y,z,vv1[x,y,z], vv2[x,y,z]))
```

This simple code does the job but slowly.

a different approach I thought of was to create a 1D long vector that each entry will be 3 indices values and then apply the same logic with the printing for example, a nested loop example:

```
vv_ind = []

for x in range(vv1.shape[0]):
    for y in range(vv1.shape[1]):
        for z in range(vv1.shape[2]):
            vv_ind.append([x,y,z])

for elem in vv_ind:
    i = tuple(elem)
    print("{:} {:} {:} {:} {:}".format(*elem, vv1[i], vv2[i]))
```

which gives the desired output.

My questions are as follows:

1. is there a more *"pythonic"* way to create that list of indices?
2. regarding the last printing loop:

   ```
   for elem in vv_ind:
       i = tuple(elem)
       print("{:} {:} {:} {:} {:}".format(*elem, vv1[i], vv2[i]))
   ```

   is there a more efficient way to do it?

Again the arrays given here are just dummy ones for ease

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list of indices you can use the function [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#//apple_ref/Function/itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

product(*3 * [range(3)]) # generator of indices
```

or

```
product(range(3), range(3), range(3))
```

or

```
from itertools import product, repeat

product(*repeat(range(3), 3))
```

You can simplify your code:

```
from itertools import product, repeat

for idx in product(*repeat(range(3), 3)):
    print(*idx, vv1[idx], vv2[idx])
```

As @a_guest mentioned in the comment we can use `np.ndindex(*vv1.shape)` instead of `product(*repeat(range(3), 3))`:

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) for generating the indices and in case you don't mind saving everything as the same data type you can just stack the arrays together and save the result via `np.save` or `np.savetxt`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                    

In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(4, 4, 4))                                         

In [3]: b = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(4, 4, 4))                                         

In [4]: data = np.stack([x.ravel() for x in np.mgrid[:4, :4, :4]] + [a.ravel(), b.ravel()], axis=1)                                                                                 

In [5]: np.save('/tmp/test.npy', data)                                                        

In [6]: data                                                                                  
Out[6]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0, 169,  35],
       [  0,   0,   1,  14, 120],
       [  0,   0,   2,  93, 207],
       [  0,   0,   3,  70, 158],
       [  0,   1,   0, 115,  52],
       [  0,   1,   1,  10, 248],
       [  0,   1,   2,   5, 123],
       [  0,   1,   3, 125, 143],
       [  0,   2,   0,  73, 241],
       [  0,   2,   1,  25, 118],
       [  0,   2,   2, 240, 159],
       [  0,   2,   3,  60, 179],
       [  0,   3,   0,  29, 221],
       [  0,   3,   1, 214,  33],
       [  0,   3,   2, 145,  60],
       [  0,   3,   3, 207,  74],
       [  1,   0,   0,   7,  37],
       [  1,   0,   1, 146, 192],
       [  1,   0,   2, 227,  83],
       [  1,   0,   3, 247,  51],
       [  1,   1,   0, 253,  18],
       [  1,   1,   1, 188,   2],
       [  1,   1,   2, 164, 252],
       [  1,   1,   3, 192, 229],
       [  1,   2,   0,  18, 236],
       [  1,   2,   1,  85,  48],
       [  1,   2,   2,  20, 233],
       [  1,   2,   3,  81, 152],
       [  1,   3,   0, 122,  30],
       [  1,   3,   1, 227, 221],
       [  1,   3,   2,  11, 247],
       [  1,   3,   3,  84, 203],
       [  2,   0,   0,   5,  94],
       [  2,   0,   1, 174, 179],
       [  2,   0,   2, 224, 222],
       [  2,   0,   3, 168,  40],
       [  2,   1,   0, 160, 136],
       [  2,   1,   1,  16, 121],
       [  2,   1,   2, 237, 241],
       [  2,   1,   3,  70,  29],
       [  2,   2,   0, 127, 188],
       [  2,   2,   1,  33,  67],
       [  2,   2,   2,   4, 138],
       [  2,   2,   3, 153, 114],
       [  2,   3,   0, 162,   8],
       [  2,   3,   1, 254,  91],
       [  2,   3,   2, 153,  69],
       [  2,   3,   3, 167,  33],
       [  3,   0,   0,  99, 101],
       [  3,   0,   1,  26,   2],
       [  3,   0,   2, 162, 131],
       [  3,   0,   3,  23,  97],
       [  3,   1,   0, 226,  37],
       [  3,   1,   1,   5, 130],
       [  3,   1,   2, 215, 164],
       [  3,   1,   3, 247,  95],
       [  3,   2,   0, 138,  49],
       [  3,   2,   1, 248, 175],
       [  3,   2,   2, 134,  39],
       [  3,   2,   3, 170,  67],
       [  3,   3,   0,   1, 177],
       [  3,   3,   1, 245,  31],
       [  3,   3,   2,  71, 160],
       [  3,   3,   3,  81,   9]])
```

Otherwise you can also use [`np.ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) for iterating over the arrays indices:

```
In [10]: with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as fh: 
    ...:     for index in np.ndindex(*a.shape): 
    ...:         data = map(str, index + (a[index], b[index])) 
    ...:         fh.write(','.join(data) + '\n')
```

Comment: I wasnt aware of `np.mgrid` thanks. I do mind that the values of the data matrices will remain floats; but the `ndindex` is also elegant solution

Comment: @DavidS I rather intended the other way round, saving the whole stacked array as `float` and hence saving the indices as float as well (not converting the actual data).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) using a structured array, if the data is not integer:

```
import numpy as np
import io

# Data
vv1 = np.array([[[  1,  2,  3], [  2,  3,  4],[  3,  4,  5]],
                [[  4,  5,  6], [  5,  6,  7],[  6,  7,  8]],
                [[  7,  8,  9], [  8,  9, 10],[  9, 10, 11]]], np.float32)
vv2 = np.array([[[  1,  2,  3], [  2,  3,  4],[  3,  4,  5]],
                [[  4,  5,  6], [  5,  6,  7],[  6,  7,  8]],
                [[  7,  8,  9], [  8,  9, 10],[  9, 10, 11]]], np.float32)

xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(*map(range, vv1.shape), indexing='ij')
# Structured array of indices and data
a = np.empty(len(idx), dtype='i,i,i,f,f')
a['f0'] = xx.ravel()
a['f1'] = yy.ravel()
a['f2'] = zz.ravel()
a['f3'] = vv1.ravel()
a['f4'] = vv2.ravel()
# Using StringIO here to show result, normally would use a file object or file name
s = io.StringIO()
np.savetxt(s, a, fmt='%d %d %d %.3f %.3f')
print(s.getvalue())
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 1.000 1.000
0 0 1 2.000 2.000
0 0 2 3.000 3.000
0 1 0 2.000 2.000
0 1 1 3.000 3.000
0 1 2 4.000 4.000
0 2 0 3.000 3.000
0 2 1 4.000 4.000
0 2 2 5.000 5.000
1 0 0 4.000 4.000
1 0 1 5.000 5.000
1 0 2 6.000 6.000
1 1 0 5.000 5.000
1 1 1 6.000 6.000
1 1 2 7.000 7.000
1 2 0 6.000 6.000
1 2 1 7.000 7.000
1 2 2 8.000 8.000
2 0 0 7.000 7.000
2 0 1 8.000 8.000
2 0 2 9.000 9.000
2 1 0 8.000 8.000
2 1 1 9.000 9.000
2 1 2 10.000 10.000
2 2 0 9.000 9.000
2 2 1 10.000 10.000
2 2 2 11.000 11.000
```

[`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) really just loops through the data internally, so it is not like it should be magically faster, though. It may not be worth creating the additional big array for it.